# Youtube Python API v3 call onBehalfOfContentOwner returns 403 error

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to search my own videos doing search with parameter onBehalfOfContentOwner=MY_CONTENT_OWNER_ID but keep getting 403 Forbidden error.

Private key is being used for authentication.

without onBehalfOfContentOwner my call works perfectly but doesn't return Tags

Comment: Are you able to get it to work using the API explorer at the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)?

Comment: yes it works there for me

Comment: By private key, do you mean OAuth authentication token? Have you granted the application access to your account?

Comment: private key is used as part of authentication with service account described here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#scenarios

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the onBehalfOfContentOwner parameter (as well as the managedByMe parameter) are available ONLY through an authorized request (and not a service account). In other words, your key is not enough, because that only gives you general-level, read access (Neither Youtube nor Google's API services associate that key with your actual Youtube account).

You'll need to set up regular oAuth2 authentication, then authenticate with your Google account and password each time you make the call, granting your client access to the call in the process, in order for those parameters to be allowed.

See the docs here for more details:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

However, if I'm wrong and service accounts can be used for these types of authorized requests, I'd love to be corrected!